# MIPS64 Android split APK no longer has "native-code" key

Tags: android, build, google-play, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I went to build our Android project for Play Store deployment today as usual. We use APK splits (via `build.gradle`, as described [here](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/30/android-ndk-version-code-scheme-for-publishing-apks-per-architecture/)) to build a separate APK for each platform architecture (and have been doing for a year, through at least a dozen releases to the Play Store).

When I uploaded my seven APKs, I noticed that unlike all previous releases, including as recently as two days ago (1/31/17), the MIPS64 APK had a blank "Native platform" in our app's APK tab.

This caused a cascading series of problems with our ability to publish the app but the end result is that we can't publish the latest release on any MIPS or MIPS64 device (that there are zero such devices available is not the issue; I want to understand what has changed).

I decided to use `aapt dump` to analyze the APKs to see if I could get any clue to what is going on. The results from our **MIPS** (not -64) build include the following:

```
package: name='com.redacted' versionCode='5000162' versionName='3.0.2' platformBuildVersionName='6.0-2704002'
...
native-code: 'mips'
```

While the MIPS64 output looks like:

```
package: name='com.redacted' versionCode='6000162' versionName='3.0.2' platformBuildVersionName='6.0-2704002'
```

*There is no `native-code` entry for the MIPS64 version.*

I can't explain why the splits now being generated have this issue with MIPS64. Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hey, have you found a answer to this?

Comment: Nope. But since it doesn't seem like there are actually any MIPS64 devices on the general market, we now omit this slice from our Play Store submissions.

Comment: Yup, we are totally doing the same! :)

Comment: Hello guys, I am facing the same problem, but for armeabi. Any suggestions as to how to debug the problem ?